# Can I access metadata annotations of a type or parameter in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Or is that capability lost with the loss of the reflect package?

What I'm curious about is can I use annotations in my own flutter app? Or is that a feature only available in dart, but not flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations can only be used for static analysis in Flutter.

For example the analyzer that generates hints and warnings in your IDE, code generation tools like built_value, built_redux, json_serializable, and other packages that use https://github.com/dart-lang/build make use of this.

There is no way to get metadata information at runtime without `dart:mirrors`.

There is work in progress to make the reflectable package work with code generation. This might work with Flutter eventually to generate code that allows to access predefined metadata at runtime.
See also https://github.com/dart-lang/reflectable/tree/use_build

Comment: About that `dart:mirrors` is no longer existed in the newer version right?

Comment: Yes, it was removed for Flutter and web, and is only available for console apps. You might want to have a look at the reflectable package, but I don't know it's status

Answer (score -2):

Yes, of course you can use metadata annotations in flutter. Flutter has a [meta-library](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/meta/meta-library.html), which you can look into to know about available annotations that can be used with flutter.

Hope this helped!

Comment: yes, but you can't access that meta during a flutter app runtime. Those are just annotations for the static tools and compiler.